# recv() function do not get message back in python

Tags: tcp

I am new to TCP/IP connection using python

I have this simple code:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("www.google.com",80))
s.send("GET /\n")
while 1: 
 received = s.recv(1024) 
 if received: 
  print received
```

but when I run it it just runs forever and does not give me any result!!!

Could you please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow [HTTP Protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)**

```
s.send("GET /\n")
```

This is not correct. You should send http data in a proper way. Use this

```
s.send("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n");
```

In fact you are to send [standard http request headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Requests).

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: www.google.com
```

Note: As [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721269/david-schwartz) says in the comment you must be able to decode chunked transfer coding. So its better you state `HTTP/1.0` in the header.

Comment: Since I really don't think he wants to deal with chunked encoding, claiming 1.1 compliance is probably not a good idea.

Comment: yes I replaced "s.send("GET /\n")" with "s.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n");" one and it works now, Thanks

Comment: @David I never had problem with that header.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: Then you got lucky. The [standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6.1) says: "All HTTP/1.1 applications MUST be able to receive and decode the "chunked" transfer-coding ..."

Comment: Another reason is that HTTP 1.1 defaults to keeping connections alive. Likely his code is going to keep reading until the connection closes, so specifying HTTP 1.1 would make his code hang.

Comment: OK I changed it to HTTP 1.0 Thanks for help

Comment: @DavidSchwartz connection can be closed just by adding "Connection: close" header.